# Navbar items on different pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

This is the Next JS code for Navbar on all pages, initially it changes the color of the elements from white to black when scrolling below 950 px, but I want the Navbar elements on another page "/lodge/page.tsx" not to change color after 950px from white to black, but to be initially black, because on this page the background is white and the elements are just not visible.

```
'use client'

import Image from "next/image"
import Link from "next/link"

import Container from "../Container"
import Logo from "./Logo"
import Contacts from "./Contacts"
import Lang from "./Lang"

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
    
    const [color, setColor] = useState(false)
    const changeColor = () => {
        if (window.scrollY >= 950 && !window.location.pathname.includes('/lodge/page.tsx')) {
            setColor(true)
        }
        else {
            setColor(false)
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', changeColor)

  return (
    <div className="fixed w-full backdrop-blur-sm shadow-sm">
        <div className="py-4 border-b-[2px]">
            <Container>
                <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between gap-4">

                    <Logo />

                    <div className="text-2xl text-white font-medium xl:pl-[632px] md:block hidden">
                        <Link 
                            href="/lodge"
                            className={color ? 'text-[#313131]' : 'text-white'}
                            >
                            LODGE
                        </Link>
                        
                    </div>

                    <div className="text-2xl text-white font-medium md:block hidden">
                        <div className={color ? 'text-[#313131]' : 'text-white'}>
                            <Link href="/blog">
                                OUR BLOG
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <Contacts />
                    <Lang />

                </div>
            </Container>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

I tried adding a condition - `(window.scrollY >= 950 && !router.pathname.includes('/lodge/page.tsx'))`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you shouldn't include `page.tsx` . just type `window.location.pathname.includes("/lodge")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition you're using is not correct. `(window.scrollY >= 950 && !window.location.pathname.includes('/lodge/page.tsx'))` means that the color will be black when scrolling BELOW 950px (`window.scrollY >= 950`) while NOT on the `/lodge/page.tsx`.

Simply remove the exclamation mark and change `>=` to `<=`:

```
(window.scrollY <= 950 && window.location.pathname.includes('/lodge/page.tsx'))
```

**Edit:** I understand now that you wish to apply that conditional color toggling globally an not only in `/lodge/page.tsx`, Here's the code:

```js
const isLodgePage = window.pathname.includes('/lodge/page.tsx')
const  [color, setColor] = useState(isLodgePage);

const changeColor = () => window.scrollY >= 950 ? setColor(!isLodgePage) : setColor(isLodgePage)
```

Comment: Nope, on all screens except '/lodge/page.tsx' the navbar elements should change from white to black after 950 px below, but in '/lodge/page.tsx' should be initially black

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to conditionally change the color of your Navbar elements based on the scroll position and the current page path in a Next.js application. The condition you're using should work with a slight modification. Here's how you can achieve the desired behavior:

```js
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import Container from "../Container";
import Logo from "./Logo";
import Contacts from "./Contacts";
import Lang from "./Lang";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router"; // Import the useRouter hook

const Navbar = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter(); // Initialize the router

  useEffect(() => {
    const changeColor = () => {
      if (window.scrollY >= 950 && router.pathname !== '/lodge/page') {
        setColor(true);
      } else {
        setColor(false);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', changeColor);

    return () => {
      // Remove the event listener when the component unmounts
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeColor);
    };
  }, [router.pathname]); // Re-run the effect when the pathname changes

  return (
    <div className="fixed w-full backdrop-blur-sm shadow-sm">
      <div className="py-4 border-b-[2px]">
        <Container>
          <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between gap-4">
            <Logo />
            <div className="text-2xl text-white font-medium xl:pl-[632px] md:block hidden">
              <Link href="/lodge" className={color ? 'text-[#313131]' : 'text-white'} >
                LODGE
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="text-2xl text-white font-medium md:block hidden">
              <div className={color ? 'text-[#313131]' : 'text-white'}>
                <Link href="/blog">OUR BLOG</Link>
              </div>
            </div>
            <Contacts />
            <Lang />
          </div>
        </Container>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

In this modified code:

1. We import the `useRouter` hook from Next.js to access the current route information.
2. We use the `useEffect` hook to add the scroll event listener and remove it when the component unmounts.
3. Inside the `changeColor` function, we check `router.pathname` (the current page path) against '/lodge/page'. If it's not the '/lodge/page' path, and the scroll position is greater than or equal to 950, we set the `color` state to `true`.

This should ensure that the Navbar elements are initially black and only change color when the conditions are met on pages other than '/lodge/page'.